# Basic4Android SQLITE LIKE Statement

Tags: sqlite, basic4android

I've been stuck with this since this morning, I'm trying to search on the database table using LIKE statement but I'm getting trouble at where to put the % sign. I already tried different approach but It's not working.

At first I tried the

```
Dim cur As Cursor
cur = Main.SQL1.ExecQuery2("SELECT * from tbl_info WHERE info_name LIKE  '%?%' ",Array As String(searchString))
```

But that does not work then I also tried this

```
Dim cur As Cursor
cur = Main.SQL1.ExecQuery2("SELECT * from tbl_info WHERE info_name LIKE  '"+searchString+"' ",Array As String(searchString))
```

But I'm getting numberformat exception even though the searchString contains Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to be like this:

```
cur = Main.SQL1.ExecQuery2("SELECT * from tbl_info WHERE info_name LIKE ?", "%" + Array As String(searchString)) + "%"
```

Now the bound parameter can be replaced and the necessary wildcards are added to it.
No need to worry about the string delimiters (`'`), since they will be added  automatically as needed, during the binding process.